# C++ - critical values probability distribution

Tags: c++, statistics, distribution, probability

were can I find reliable code for critical values for probability distributions? For instance, F critical values for the fisher test...
?

Thanks for any relevant reference.

Comment: Check out http://www.alglib.net/

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I looked in alglib sources already. In file specialfunction.cpp, there are some functions as fdistribution that are relevant, but they are just calling other methods that I cannot find, such as alglib_impl::fdistribution. I checked several other source files in alglib without finding the base code with explicit 'computation' of criticla values.

Comment: Did you try to just use the library itself and see if it works?

Comment: I cannot use alglib or any third praty library here, but want to reproduce rapidly a stats class.

Comment: `alglib_impl::fdistribution` is on line 8241 of `specialfunctions.cpp`. Used find to get that one...

Comment: sorry, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: This heavily depends on the test. For very standard tests, like xhi^2 or F, you just need the quantiles of a Gamma resp. a F distribution (which are easily available, the first one is an incomplete gamma function, the second one is expressed by incomplete beta. For Student's t, it is a hypergeometric function -- 2F1 to be precise). For more complex tests, this might be something you have to compute yourself (approximations for Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Cramér-Von Mises are standard too, albeit more complex). Please specify which tests you are interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Boost Math Toolkit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/index.html) contains the [F distribution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/f_dist.html). To get critical values, use the [quantile non-member function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/nmp.html#math.dist.quantile). If you can't use any third party tools, then you are in for a lot of work since most distributions do not have a closed form analytical expression for critical values. E.g. the normal distribution requires numerical integration.

Answer (score 1):

I hope they re-propose [statistical special functions for C++ TR2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1668.pdf).  Also Boost has a [similar proposal](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/04/46589.php).  I know that doesn't help now but I think this stuff should be canned for everyone to just pick up and use.